# Invalid frequency: SM-15 in pandas.Series.dt.to_period

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying and unable to cast dates to half-month periods. I don't know whether this is a pandas bug or not, so I'm posting here using the issue format.

### Code Sample

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create column, cast to datetime
a = ['2018-04-01', '2018-04-06', '2018-04-10', '2018-04-20', '2018-04-25']
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['a'])
df['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df['a'])

# Attempt to cast to half-month periods
df['a'].dt.to_period('SM')
```

Generates this traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/tslibs/frequencies.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.frequencies._period_str_to_code()

KeyError: 'SM-15'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-b954dd6bd134> in <module>
----> 1 df['a'].dt.to_period('SM')

~/local/anaconda3/envs/create-database/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/accessor.py in f(self, *args, **kwargs)
     91         def _create_delegator_method(name):
     92             def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
---> 93                 return self._delegate_method(name, *args, **kwargs)
     94 
     95             f.__name__ = name

~/local/anaconda3/envs/create-database/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/accessors.py in _delegate_method(self, name, *args, **kwargs)
    107 
    108         method = getattr(values, name)
--> 109         result = method(*args, **kwargs)
    110 
    111         if not is_list_like(result):

~/local/anaconda3/envs/create-database/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/accessor.py in f(self, *args, **kwargs)
     91         def _create_delegator_method(name):
     92             def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
---> 93                 return self._delegate_method(name, *args, **kwargs)
     94 
     95             f.__name__ = name

~/local/anaconda3/envs/create-database/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimelike.py in _delegate_method(self, name, *args, **kwargs)
    811 
    812     def _delegate_method(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
--> 813         result = operator.methodcaller(name, *args, **kwargs)(self._data)
    814         if name not in self._raw_methods:
    815             result = Index(result, name=self.name)

~/local/anaconda3/envs/create-database/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in to_period(self, freq)
   1280             freq = get_period_alias(freq)
   1281 
-> 1282         return PeriodArray._from_datetime64(self._data, freq, tz=self.tz)
   1283 
   1284     def to_perioddelta(self, freq):

~/local/anaconda3/envs/create-database/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/period.py in _from_datetime64(cls, data, freq, tz)
    273         PeriodArray[freq]
    274         """
--> 275         data, freq = dt64arr_to_periodarr(data, freq, tz)
    276         return cls(data, freq=freq)
    277 

~/local/anaconda3/envs/create-database/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/period.py in dt64arr_to_periodarr(data, freq, tz)
    914         data = data._values
    915 
--> 916     base, mult = libfrequencies.get_freq_code(freq)
    917     return libperiod.dt64arr_to_periodarr(data.view("i8"), base, tz), freq
    918 

pandas/_libs/tslibs/frequencies.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.frequencies.get_freq_code()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/frequencies.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.frequencies.get_freq_code()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/frequencies.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.frequencies.get_freq_code()

pandas/_libs/tslibs/frequencies.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.frequencies._period_str_to_code()

ValueError: Invalid frequency: SM-15
```

### Problem description

I'm trying to cast dates to half-month periods. The [docs for `pandas.Series.dt.to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) say 
to pass one of the [offset strings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases), of which `SM` is one.

It does say that a `ValueError` is raised when "converting a DatetimeArray/Index with non-regular values, so that a frequency cannot be inferred". But I don't understand what this means, and I haven't found anything on StackOverflow or the pandas issue tracker that explains this error.

### Expected Output

I expected

```py
df['a'].dt.to_period('SM')
```

to give:

```
0    2018-04-15
1    2018-04-15
2    2018-04-15
3    2018-04-30
4    2018-04-30
Name: a, dtype: period[SM-15]
```

Output of `pd.show_versions()`

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit           : None
python           : 3.7.3.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Darwin
OS-release       : 19.2.0
machine          : x86_64
processor        : i386
byteorder        : little
LC_ALL           : None
LANG             : en_US.UTF-8
LOCALE           : en_US.UTF-8

pandas           : 0.25.3
numpy            : 1.17.3
pytz             : 2019.3
dateutil         : 2.8.1
pip              : 19.3.1
setuptools       : 41.6.0.post20191101
Cython           : None
pytest           : 5.3.1
hypothesis       : 4.50.8
sphinx           : None
blosc            : None
feather          : None
xlsxwriter       : None
lxml.etree       : 4.4.1
html5lib         : None
pymysql          : None
psycopg2         : None
jinja2           : 2.10.3
IPython          : 7.9.0
pandas_datareader: None
bs4              : 4.8.1
bottleneck       : None
fastparquet      : None
gcsfs            : None
lxml.etree       : 4.4.1
matplotlib       : 3.1.2
numexpr          : None
odfpy            : None
openpyxl         : None
pandas_gbq       : None
pyarrow          : 0.15.1
pytables         : None
s3fs             : None
scipy            : 1.3.2
sqlalchemy       : None
tables           : None
xarray           : None
xlrd             : 1.2.0
xlwt             : None
xlsxwriter       : None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the sample from the [docs](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/timeseries.html) that is not how you use `SM` when the input is a series.

I'm still not sure who to use `to_period`; however this does get the expected output

```
df['a'] + pd.offsets.SemiMonthEnd()

0   2018-04-15
1   2018-04-15
2   2018-04-15
3   2018-04-30
4   2018-04-30
Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Oh wow. I would've expected adding a SemiMonthEnd offset to add roughly 15 days to each item, so that the second item would be ~ 2018-04-21.